# Heat equation problem with initial condition in a disk

Tags: integration, proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, greens-function

I was solving this problem

> Find the solution $u(x,y,t)$ of the problem 
>   $$
> \begin{cases} 
> u_t=D\nabla^2u \\[5pt]
> u(x,y=0,t) = 0\\[5pt]
> u(x,y,0) = \phi(x,y)
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   where 
>   $$
> \phi(x,y) = \begin{cases} c &(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\le R^2 \\[5pt] 0 & (x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\gt R^2 \end{cases}$$ then find an approximate solution in the region $$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2\gg R^2$$ 
>   $\underline{\textbf{Hint:}}$ Note that the Dirac delta function is given by the limit when $R\rightarrow \infty$ of the function $$\frac{1}{\pi R^2}\chi_R (x,y)$$ where $$\chi_R(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1& x^2+y^2\le R \\ 0&x^2+y^2\gt R\end{cases}$$

and I got stuck evaluating the following integral: taking the convolution between the heat kernel and the initial condition $$u(x,y,t) = \frac{1}{4\pi Dt}\iint_{\mathbb R^2} e^{-\frac{|\underline{x}-\underline{x}'|^2}{4Dt}}u(\underline{x}',0)\,\mathrm d^2\underline x' = \frac{c}{4\pi Dt}\iint\limits_{\Omega} e^{-\frac{|\underline{x}-\underline{x}'|^2}{4Dt}}\,\mathrm d^2\underline x'$$ where $\Omega$ is the region limited by the disk centered in $(x_0, y_0)$ of radius $R$.

I've tried going to polar coordinates, which seems to me the right choice, but I haven't got very far: $$\begin{cases} x' = x_0+r\cos\theta \\ y'=y_0+r\sin\theta\end{cases}$$ which gives me $$u(x,y,t) = \frac{c}{4\pi Dt}e^{(x^2+y^2)+(x_0^2+y_0^2)-2(x_0+y_0)}\int\limits_0^R\int\limits_0^{2\pi}r^2\sin(\theta) e^{-2r[\cos\theta(1-x_0)+\sin\theta(1-y_0)]+r^2}\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$$ here's where I'm stuck.

> How do I proceed? Are my calculations correct?

Sorry for the late correction, I forgot the Jacobian when changing the variables.

Comment: Are you sure you don't miss some square somewhere? cos and sin would be inside norm squared, wouldnt they?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, in fact there's the $r^2$ term in the exponential which comes from $r^2\sin^2\theta+r^2\cos^2\theta$!

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes, that is what I suspected. In general a good idea to take smaller steps when simplifying. It's very easy to miss something otherwise.

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, my bad. I wrote down less steps that I should had :(

Comment: So where does Green's theorem come in play? Can you use it to turn it from a 2 variable integral to a one variable integral?

Comment: @mathreadler Mhhhh..i'm not very familiar with using green's identities to solve PDE's. Although I've some idea on what they're about I don't really know how to use them..could you help me with the calculations? Surely there's a way of converting that surface integral into a line integral but I cannot se how atm

Comment: I am also pretty sure there is some way, but it was such a long time ago I did this on paper. I will try bumping it for you and maybe some integral master comes along. Hmm, seems there is some time limit for bumping. Maybe after work tomorrow.

Comment: Eh, seems be longer requirement to wait for bounty than I remembered.

Comment: @mathreadler ops came back to uni the other day and I totally forgot :P

Comment: so did you solve it or what happened?

Comment: @mathreadler No, I really didn't and I don't really know how to solve it still

Comment: You're missing boundary conditions, this is in some rectangle right. Like $0 \leq x \leq L $,  $0 \leq y \leq H$  and you're saying the initial condition is $\phi(x,y)$ or are saying it is actually a disk. $0 \leq  r \leq a$

Comment: without the other boundaries you won't be able to figure out the eigenvalues

Comment: @RHowe It's a problem on the right half plane! I'm afraid we cannot use eigendecomposition

Comment: @DavideMorgante uhh I didn't go this far. I think you need to use Fourier transforms.  Maybe I'll read about it

Comment: @RHowe Yes, Fourier transform got me the green's function for the problem. In fact the issue is with the last integral which is the convolution between the green function and the initial conditions

Comment: What book are you using?

Comment: @RHowe For my course we used 4/5 books + the professor notes!

Comment: I'd note the following $u(x,y,0) = \phi(x,y) $ is the disk however $\frac{1}{4\pi D t} $ blows up at $t=0$ where it should be a disk no?

Comment: Is $|y_0|>R$ in your premise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, suppose $x_0=0,\ y_0>0,\ D=\frac12,\ c\pi R^2=1$.

1. $y_0\ge R$.

By Green's function of the heat equation $u(x,y\le0,t)=0$.

For $y>0$, the $u$ in the upper half plane is equivalent to the upper half plane solution of whole plane solution of from the original source and its negative image $-\Omega$ reflected across the line $y=0$, since the latter satisfies the PDE and its zero boundary condition on $y=0$.
\begin{align}
u(x,y>0,t) &= \frac c{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\Big(\int_{\Omega}dudv\, e^{-\frac{(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2}{2t}}-\int_{-\Omega}dudv\, e^{-\frac{(x-u)^2+(y-v)^2}{2t}}\Big) \\
&\underset{x^2+y^2\to\infty}\sim\ \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\Big( e^{-\frac{x^2+(y-y_0)^2}{2t}}-e^{-\frac{x^2+(y+y_0)^2}{2t}}\Big) \\
&=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi t}}\,e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2+y_0^2}{2t}}\sinh\Big(\frac{yy_0}t\Big).
\end{align}
We have treated the source as one point, as at large distance the exact shape $\Omega$ of the source impacts little on the final approximation.

2. $y_0<R$.

The disk is cut into two parts by $y=0$. We still treat the upper and lower half of the plane separately. This time the total "energy" of positive source is a fraction proportional to its area above $y=0$. $u$ no longer vanishes in the lower half plane but is evaluated similarly to that in the upper half plane.

Comment: I couldn't have asked for more! Thank you so much, the bounty is yours :)

Comment: @DavideMorgante: You are welcome. :-)